# what if variable changes after settimeout but before it really run

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
function fun(x){alert(x);}

var i=1;
var t=setTimeout(function(){ fun(i) },10000);
i=2;
```

so when the fun(x) really runs,what will be alerted.

if the result is 2,how to make x be 1.

for some reason,i cannot use a global variable.

thx

---

update
in fact,i need to use such thing in a for(){} thing;

so maybe the best way is like this:

```
setTimeout("testDisplay(" + aa + "," + bb + ")",1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an extra scope. That works in every browser.

```
var i=1, t;
(function () {
   var tmp = i;
   t=setTimeout(function(){ fun(tmp) },10000);
})();

i=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fun(x){alert(x);}

var i=1;
var iCopy = i;
var t=setTimeout(function(){ fun(iCopy) },10000);
i=2;
```